# Codeigniter 2.1, PHP - get random array from key value pair

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have query from which I need to take random values (random rows) and limit to, lets say, 5 results and subtract them from main array (query). How can I do this?

This is query function:

```
public function galerija_jedna_slike()
    {
        $galerija = $this->db->order_by('id_galerija', 'RANDOM')->limit(1)->get($this->table)->row();
        $q = " SELECT * FROM galerija_slike
                LEFT JOIN galerije
                ON galerija_slike.galerija_id = galerije.id_galerija
                WHERE galerija_id = $galerija->id_galerija ";
        return $this->db->query($q)->result_array();
    }
```

I managed to get random values, and now I need to remove those values from the main array. Function:

```
function array_random_assoc($arr, $num = 1) {
        $keys = array_keys($arr);
        shuffle($keys);

        $r = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
        $r[$keys[$i]] = $arr[$keys[$i]];
        }
        return $r;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the entire table:

```
$gallery =  $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM gallery;");
```

Let choose five random rows from gallery:

```
$max_items = 5;
$num = $query->num_rows();
$row = $query->row(rand(0, $num - 1));
$minus = array(); //store the ids to include

for ($i = 0; $i < $max_items; $i ++)
    $minus[] = $gallery ->row(rand(0, $num - 1));
```

Iterate the gallery to build two arrays, 1. Gallery minus random rows 2. Random rows

```
$data = array();
foreach ($gallery ->result() as $row)
{
    if (in_array($row->id, $minus))
        $data['random'][] = $row
    else
        $data['gallery'][] = $row
}
```

Now, the array `$data['gallery']` has all the items without the randon rows. And `$data[random]` is an array containing the random rows.

Comment: This will not do. I need all results from the query. In the view page, I have two parts - one for random results from the query and the rest for the rest.

Comment: Sasha, I can understand. `one for random results from the query and the rest for the rest`. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Ooops, my bad. It is like this - on the page I have two parts, one part is for the random values taken from original array (query) and the other part on the page is for the query minus random values taken (small gallery with 5 results, and big gallery with the rest of the query).

Comment: Ok, one second. Let me try

Comment: I managed to get random values, so there is a second part to be solved. How to remove that values from the main array (query)?

Comment: Will do. From what I can see, it solves the problem. Let me just test the code.

Comment: There is two problem for generating random entries. 1. It does not take account if database return less than 5 entries. 2. Code will break if same random number is generated multiple times and it will happen in many case.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved in 3 part.

1. First the query. You have already done that and I will start from there.
2. You need to generate 5 unique integer within the range of returned array. You also have to be careful in case less than 5 results are returned. Here is the code for that.

   ```
    $random_integer = array();
    for( $i=0; $i<5 && $i<(count($a)-1); $i++){
       while( 1 ){
           $random_value = rand(0, count($a)-1);
           if( in_array($random_value, $random_integer) ){
               continue;
           }
           else{
               $random_integer[] = $random_value;
               break;
          }
       }
    }
   ```

Now you have 5 unique random integer in `$random_integer`, within the range of your returned result. If less than 6 entries are returned from query, 1 will be used for normal post and rest will be used for random post. You can change that in the condition of for loop. `in_array` will check for any duplicate entry.

1. The last part is to set these random queries in a separate variable and also truncate them from main queries. You can do it like this. Say, the returned query is `$main_query`

   ```
       foreach( $random_integer as $row ){
           $random_query[] = $main_query[$row];
           unset($main_query[$row]);
       }
       $main_query = array_values($main_query);
   ```

`unset` will not change the array keys. `array_values` function will normalize the array keys. Now `$random_query` will contain 5(max) random queries and `$main_query` will contain the rest of the queries.

Answer (score 0):

This should give some idea. Note: Code not tested.

```
public function galerija_jedna_slike()
{
    $galerija = $this->db->order_by('id_galerija', 'RANDOM')->limit(1)->get($this->table)->row();
    //query to get only id
    $q = "SELECT id FROM galerija_slike WHERE galerija_id = $galerija->id_galerija ";

    $result = $this->db->query($q)->result_array();

    $ids = array();
    foreach($result as $row){
        $ids[] = $row['id'];
    }

    //shuffle id arrays or other function to randomize
    shuffle($ids);

    $ids = array_slice($ids,0,5);//gets first 5 ids

    $sql = " SELECT * FROM galerija_slike
                    LEFT JOIN galerije
                    ON galerija_slike.galerija_id = galerije.id_galerija
                    WHERE galerija_id = $galerija->id_galerija AND id IN(".implode(',', $ids).")";

    return $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
}
```